# Patch objects created by plt.hist() do not get drawn

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Let me preface this by saying that my understanding of matplotlib is limited - I mostly just use `plot()`, `hist()` and `show()` from pyplot. I have a basic understanding of what patch objects are, but (evidently) do not properly understand how to work with them.

When I run the following piece of code (copied from a standard online example):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Wedge, Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

resolution = 50  # the number of vertices
N = 3
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
radii = 0.1*np.random.rand(N)
patches = []
for x1, y1, r in zip(x, y, radii):
    circle = Circle((x1, y1), r)
    patches.append(circle)

x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
radii = 0.1*np.random.rand(N)
theta1 = 360.0*np.random.rand(N)
theta2 = 360.0*np.random.rand(N)
for x1, y1, r, t1, t2 in zip(x, y, radii, theta1, theta2):
    wedge = Wedge((x1, y1), r, t1, t2)
    patches.append(wedge)

# Some limiting conditions on Wedge
patches += [
    Wedge((.3, .7), .1, 0, 360),             # Full circle
    Wedge((.7, .8), .2, 0, 360, width=0.05),  # Full ring
    Wedge((.8, .3), .2, 0, 45),              # Full sector
    Wedge((.8, .3), .2, 45, 90, width=0.10),  # Ring sector
]

for i in range(N):
    polygon = Polygon(np.random.rand(N, 2), True)
    #patches.append(polygon)

colors = 100*np.random.rand(len(patches))
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(p)
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

it behaves as expected, creating and displaying a variety of random patches: [image: An example output of the code producing random patches.]

I also know that, when I use `plt.hist()` to create and display a histogram, I can save the created patch objects to a list, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [np.random.normal(1) for i in range(10000)]
num_bins = 50

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, num_bins)
plt.show()
```

This allows me to draw the histogram. But if I do not want to draw it directly, but instead want to pass this `patches` list to the drawing functionality from the first block of code (for example, after having used functions such as `set_height()` to make some alterations), I only get an empty plot.

By using things like `print(str(len(patches)))` or `print(str(patches[10].get_height()))`, I can confirm that the patch objects are indeed created, and appear to have all the appropriate properties. So why don't I see anything when I try to draw them, using code which I *know* works for a different list of patches?

(This question was originally about a very specific thing I wanted to do with these patch objects - thanks to a helpful comment from [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest), I have now solved my problem in a different way. I have now revised my question to only be about the underlying issue.)

Comment: We can't know why the patches don't behave like you expect them to, because we don't know what you tried. (If you have a question about code, show code, as in [mcve].) However, are you aware of the `weights` argument of `hist`?

Comment: That... looks like it will completely fix my problem. Thank you! I'll revise the question completely to be exclusively about why the patches from plt.hist() do not appear to work properly, since I'm still curious about that.

Comment: You now have a lot of code in question but none that is about the patches from the `hist`. To be concrete here, you will want to show the code that "pass this patches list to the drawing functionality from the first block" as you put it.